# Memory leak when cloning byte[] in a loop - Android

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, clone

I am streaming RTSP from my Android device using [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming). I also want to record video when I press the button while streaming. I started a thread inside the net\majorkernelpanic\streaming\video\VideoStream.java class to record video. I am posting **camera** and **data** objects from **onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)** to this thread. When I send the **data** using Arrays.copyOf(), System.arrayCopy() or data.clone(), OutOfMemory is occurs. When I send **data** directly, there is no memory leak, but color shift occurs in the video. I would be happy if you can help.

[Capture frame from Video using data without clone() or etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtO6Y.jpg)

[Profiler - clicked record video button at second 00:20,769](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myast.png)

**VideoStream.java**

```
   recordVideoThread.start();

   Camera.PreviewCallback callback = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
        long now = System.nanoTime()/1000;
        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            now = System.nanoTime()/1000;

            if (RtspServerActivity.getRecordVideoButtonActive()){
                //Creating object to add bytelist
                RecordParameters recordParameters = new RecordParameters(data, camera);
                //Adding objects to list
                recordVideo.addByteToList(recordParameters);
            }
```

**RecordParameters**

```
public class RecordParameters {
    private static final String TAG = "RecordParameters";

    private byte[] byteData;
    private Camera camera_obj;

    public RecordParameters(byte[] byteData, Camera camera_obj) {
        this.byteData = byteData;
        this.camera_obj = camera_obj;
    }

    public RecordParameters(){}

    public byte[] getByteData() {
        return byteData;
    }

    public Camera getCamera_obj() {
        return camera_obj;
    }

    public void recordVideo(byte[] byteData, Camera camera_obj, VideoWriter videoWriter)  {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera_obj.getParameters();
        int width = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
        int height = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;
        YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(byteData, parameters.getPreviewFormat(), width, height, null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 100, out);
        Mat mat = yuvtoMat(out);
        videoWriter.write(mat);
        mat.release();
    }

    public Mat yuvtoMat(ByteArrayOutputStream baos){
        return Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(baos.toByteArray()), Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR);
    }

}
```

**RecordVideoThread**

```
public class RecordVideoThread extends Thread {
    private final String TAG = "RecordVideo";
    boolean isVideoRecording = false;
    List<RecordParameters> byteList = new ArrayList<>();
    VideoWriter videoWriter = null;
    RecordParameters recordParameters = new RecordParameters();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            if(byteList.size()!=0){
                if(videoWriter == null){
                    long now = System.nanoTime();
                    Camera.Parameters parameters = byteList.get(0).getCamera_obj().getParameters();
                    int width = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
                    int height = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;
                    int frameRate = parameters.getPreviewFrameRate();
                    Size frameSize = new Size(width, height);
                    Log.i(TAG, "VideoWriter is null");
                    videoWriter= new VideoWriter(
                            "/data/data/com.example.RTSP/files/" + now + ".avi",
                            VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J','P','G'),
                            frameRate,
                            frameSize,
                            true);

                    Log.i(TAG, "videowriter "+ width +" "+height+" "+frameRate);
                }
                //Log.i(TAG, "byte list   "+ byteList.size()+"   "+ Arrays.toString(byteList.get(0).getByteData()));
                recordParameters.recordVideo(byteList.get(0).getByteData(),byteList.get(0).getCamera_obj(), videoWriter);
                byteList.remove(byteList.get(0));
                System.gc();
                System.runFinalization();
                isVideoRecording = true;
            }
            if(!RtspServerActivity.getRecordVideoButtonActive() & isRunning()){
                Log.i(TAG, "Video Writer released");
                videoWriter.release();
                stopRecord();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtO6Y.jpg) looks like an image I would take on an old/unfocused/incorrectly configured/plugged-in camera, that might not be the result of the memory leak. Also, I suggest not cloning arrays too much since it doubles the memory used by the array. In other words, use the original array when it's performance and/or memory-wise.

Comment: @JumperBot_ When I create an image using **byte data from the camera** with clone(), the image comes out fine. But as you said, this event increases memory usage and causes OutOfMemory in the loop. The original sequence leads to the above [distorted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtO6Y.jpg). There must be another way to record video without OutOfMemory and without using the original data.

Comment: Have you tried to **modify the methods** that need them so that you can just process it one byte at a time? If not, you might need to **lower the resolution** to lower memory usage even if the UX suffers drastically.

Comment: When I send 30 frames per second, the method I use cannot keep up with the speed of the accumulating frames. Since my arraylist holding byte[]s is inflated, it becomes OOM. I don't know how to solve this. Lowering resolution is not a solution for my project.